# Base class catch not catching exception even if it is appearing before derived class catch

Tags: c++, exception

Please see the expected flow of below code

In this case base class exception is catching as this expected behavior due to its polymorphic nature.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
using namespace std;
void main() {

    try {
        //throw CustomException();
        throw bad_alloc();
    }
    ///due to poly morphism base class reference will
    catch(exception &ex) {
        cout<<"Base :"<<ex.what()<<endl;
    }

    catch(bad_alloc &ex) {
        cout<<"Derieved :"<<ex.what()<<endl;
    }
}
```

output

> ```
>  bad_alloc
> ```

But if I am making a custom exception like shown in the below code, the derived class is catching the exception, even if the base class catch is appearing first in the `catch` blocks:

```
class CustomException : exception {

public :
     CustomException() { }

     const char * what() const throw() {
         // throw new exception();
         return "Derived Class Exception !";
     }
};

void main() {
    try {
        throw CustomException();
        //throw bad_alloc();
    }
    ///due to poly morphism base class reffrence will
    catch(exception &ex) {
        cout<<"Base :"<<ex.what()<<endl;
    }

    catch(CustomException &ex) {
        cout<<"Derived :"<<ex.what()<<endl;
    }
}
```

expected output :

> ```
> Base : Derived Class Exception !
> ```

Actual output:

> ```
> Derived: Derived Class Exception !
> ```

Comment: Which compiler and which version of that compiler?

Comment: In c++ main is required to have the return type `int`.

Comment: `class CustomException : exception` -> `class CustomException : public exception`?

Comment: One should generally catch exceptions by `const T&` rather than `T&`. Just saying.

Comment: `iostream.h`, `void main`, is this TurboC++?

Comment: VC++ but i got solution thanks for reply

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default inheritance access specifier for classes declared using the `class` keyword is `private`.  This means that `CustomException` inherits from `exception` `private`ly.  A derived class that uses `private` inheritance can't be bound to a reference to its parent class.

If you inherit `public`ly it will work fine:

```
class CustomException : public exception // <-- add public keyword here
{
public :
     CustomException()
     {
     }

     const char * what()
     {
         return "Derived Class Exception !";
     }
};

int main()
{

    try
    {
        throw CustomException();
    }
    catch(exception &ex)
    {
        cout<<"Base :"<<ex.what()<<endl;
    }

    catch(CustomException &ex)
    {
        cout<<"Derived :"<<ex.what()<<endl;
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f729cd95b064119)